# Set focus on a running Activity

Tags: android, focus, background, foreground

I have an Activity that keeps running after the HOME button is pressed (naturally) and of-course the focus is in the home screen, and when the running process ends i need to restore the focus on that activity.

Comment: "when the running process ends i need to restore the focus on that activity" -- what does this mean?

Comment: Imagine that u need to SEE the alarm to stop it right, but when u when to sleep the phone went home and block.

Well, i need to see my app again without intervention.

Answer (score 1):

Put a notification like GMail, Calendar, AppStore...